# Multple FTP Connection on Apache Net

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp

Scenario. More threads. Every thread would like to open a own FTP connection to same FTP Server. That's because I have a `BlockingQueue` of Files to send and I want that every Thread take a single file for Queue to process.

Now: My FTPClass is something like this (Just Constructor Providing).

```
public class FtpHandler {

    private boolean login;
    private boolean connect;
    private final String server;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private int replyCode;
    private String replyString;
    private final int ftpMbSize;

    private FTPClient ftpClient;

    public FtpHandler(String server, String username, String password, int ftpMbSize) throws SocketException, IOException {

        this.server = server;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.login = false;
        this.ftpMbSize = ftpMbSize;

        ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(this.server);

        replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        replyString = ftpClient.getReplyString();

        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
            connect = true;
            if (ftpClient.login(username, password)) {
                login = true;
            } else {
                login = false;
                connect = false;
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } else {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
            connect = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Perfect, now every thread (called `Sender`), in the run method does something like this:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        FtpHandler ftpHandler = null;

        try {
            logger.info(jobname, "OPEN CONNECTION FTP TO " + appConfig.getSender_ftp_name());
            /*
             * IF FTP HANDLER THROW AN ERROR
             * -> CATCH GOES IN ACTION
             */
            ftpHandler = new FtpHandler(appConfig.getSender_ftp_ip(),
                    appConfig.getSender_ftp_username(),
                    appConfig.getSender_ftp_password(),
                    appConfig.getSender_ftp_bufferSize_Mb());
        } catch (Throwable thw) {
           //Do Something to handle exception
        } finally {
            //IF FTP IS CONNECTED -> CLOSE IT
            if (ftpHandler != null && (ftpHandler.isLogin() || ftpHandler.isConnect())) {
                ftpHandler.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

So now, as you can see, Every thread create a own instance of FtpHandler Class, so it can manage for itself the FTP connection.

And now problem: It happens, pretty much every time (it occurs also to do not happens), that Just a Single thread can properly open connection to do something (well, this thread will manage all files), meanwhile the other threads will just wait for first one to close it to be able to Open.

I wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

TL;DR: Is it possible to open different FTP connection to same FTP Server?

Adding Controller class implementation that create BlockingQueue and Threads:

```
        BlockingQueue<FileRec> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(filesList.size());
        for (FileRec fileRec : filesList) {
            queue.add(fileReccomender);
        }

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 1; i <= appConfig.getController_sender_nThreads() && i <= filesList.size(); i++) {
            Sender sender = new Sender(queue, i);
            executor.execute(sender);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
```

Comment: Where is your code instantiating the threads, it's hard to say without it

Comment: Well, does it really matter? I mean, I think I provided all things

Comment: Yes as well as your implementation of the blocking queue, we have only partial information here the producer is missing

Comment: No matter, never mind.

Comment: Provided controller code where queue and thread are created

Comment: Thanks it helps to get it a little better, checking your code, client wise, the two possibilities I see would be that "getController_sender_nThreads()" returns 1, "filesList.size() " returns 1. Do you have the FTP server's config available?

Comment: that's totally not the problem. Threads are been created correctly (I have a logging message for this) but they just will wait in the `ftpHandler = new FtpHandler`

Comment: Exactly why I asked if you have the FTP's config... Since the scenario in my previous comment seems highly unlikely

Comment: Oh you mean in FTP Server config. I've set unlimited connection limits, wait gonna add my ftp server config

Comment: There in the `ftpHandler = new FtpHandler` does it wait *exactly*? (as that's a pretty complex expression).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I need to add some log to understand where, gonna try and update my question

Comment: Why don't you just debug your code?

Comment: Because multithreading, i find a little bit easier to just add some print statements 